# How to forward http request from old route to new route retaining http method and queries

Tags: laravel, rest, .htaccess, http, web

I hope i can finally get help over here.

i want to forward all request from old path to new path and retaining the method and queries.

**OLD URL PATH:**

```
[POST|GET|PUT|DELETE]: mydomain.com/public/api?key=value
```

**Desired URL PATH:**

```
[POST|GET|PUT|DELETE]: mydomain.com/api?key=value
```

Please can any one help me with the `.htaccess` code to achieve above idea.

Comment: What do you mean by old path and new path? did you change server or what?

Comment: i changed the root domain dir from `root` to `root/public`.
i have a domain: `mydomain.com` the root was pointing to `root` so i changed it to `root/public`.
with this change there are some applications that still send request to the old url `mydomian.com/public/api` so i would like to forward all request from that path to `mydoman.com/api`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out from within the app.

I had to get all request from old url and remove the public path from the url and allow laravel to handle them as a new request such that `domain.com/public/api` will become `domain.com/api`.

### Capture requests from old url from RouteServiceProvider.

```php
...
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Route;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
     ...
     public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::middleware('web')
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            // handle apps using old api path
            Route::any('public/api/{any}', function (Request $request) {
                // remove public from path
                $paths = explode('/', $request->path());
                $path = implode('/', array_slice($paths, 1));
                 
                // update request with new path
                $request->server->set('REQUEST_URI', $path);
                $request->server->set('PATH_INFO', $path);
                 
                // handle as a new request
                return app()->handle($request);
              })
              ->middleware('api')
              ->where('any', '.*');
        });
    }
  ...
```

[more info from medium post](https://myckhel.medium.com/how-to-safely-change-laravel-root-domain-from-to-public-folder-after-deployment-in-ed745dc743a8)